# RESTful webservice architecture and tokens

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosuserbundle

So I was able to log in users via a REST interface in symfony. However what I am not clear is how to access data in subsequent REST calls.

For example I log in the user and return the $user array which is something like:

```
{"success":true,"user":{"id":1,"username":"jini","username_canonical":"jini","email":"jini@email.com","email_canonical":"jini@email.com","enabled":true,"salt":"n0ad2gbrzasc8s0sso0so408ggokwo4","password":"RzxZoVc2raTH0ORMfoSGqifjCn1M\/LmtemDb6som7z6\/Pao2G4M0KNGs32t3jSCIYadKGJQBsdCB8ihuJv9NYQ==","confirmation_token":"685jmhhtsr0oso44w00k0wck0goo8gs8w4gwc0cwogkskwkk0c","groups":[],"locked":false,"expired":false,"roles":[],"credentials_expired":false}}
```

How do I then use the information (token/user etc.) to request each subsequent webservice call? That is do I pass in a $user parameter with each URL to ensure that the resource is valid?

Any tips and guideline will be appreciated and I am sorry if my question appears to be vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up for example the header to pass username and password and then read them and validate on server. You could add some api secret key. For example:

```
//pseudocode
$request->Headers["X-Auth-User"] = $user;
$request->Headers["X-Auth-Key"] = $key;
$request->send(); //curl for example
```

Then you can set up additional firewall to handle authenticaton on serv via securitybundle.